# Combo Box Databinding in WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a combobox in a wpf form. I would like to bind it to a table in MS SQL server. However each time i run my code i keep on running into errors. Any assistance would be appreciated. Below is my code:

```
   private void OnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FillComboBox();
    }
    protected void FillComboBox()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT RegNumber,Make FROM Vehicles GROUP BY RegNumber,Make", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(ds);
            combovehicle.DisplayMemberPath = "RegNumber"; 
            combovehicle.SelectedValue= "Make";     
            combovehicle.DataContext = ds.Tables[0];   
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Errors? What errors?

Comment: the data is not diplayed when the combo box is clicked

Comment: Does it produce an exception or does it just not behave as expected? If the former, what is it?

Comment: I handled the exception but the data is not saved into the Passengers Table(as i have named it)

Comment: You need to share the XAML for the combobox also because setting the datacontext does not necessarily set the itemssource for it. Modifying the code to say ```combovehicle.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0];``` will probably work for this code.

Comment: <ComboBox x:Name="combovehicle" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="470,118,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="254"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
combovehicle.DisplayMemberPath = "RegNumber"; 
combovehicle.SelectedValue= "Make";     
combovehicle.DataContext = ds.Tables[0];
```

So you told WPF to display using the property `Make` and `RegNumber`

but you passed in a `DataTable` object

`DataRow` does provide indexer for accessing the property but it does NOT contain those properties. Plus `DataTable` is not `IEnumerable` so you can't really use it as data source.

AND most importantly you are doing it all wrong. You should almost never make database call directly in your view and set the data source to the output table. You should do this thru MVVM pattern.

Comment: So meaning I'll have to define the  binding path within the Item Source in the XAML. forgive my ignorance but am pretty new at this

Comment: @NicksonLukalaga I would suggest putting the DB access in your view model and use xaml to bind to it. Looks like there is a way to bind to the DefaultView property of the datatable directly. Or you can make a List of custom objects and bind to that instead